# How to rebuild go project efficiently while using Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, go, build, docker-compose, build-time

This may be a stupid question, but I'm new to using Docker-compose. So far, I love it... but I'm having some long build times. I have a project with several dependencies, and I need to obviously rebuild the source every time I make a change. Right now, I'm calling `docker-compose build` to rebuild the container, followed by a `docker-compose up`. The problem is:

1. It's rebuilding the entire container for every change I make to the source code (which takes a long time -- fetching dependencies/etc). This is significantly slowing me down.
2. I really feel like I should just be able to run a command on the container to rebuild and then re-run the executable, like-so:

   ```
   docker-compose run web go build .
   docker-compose run web ./app
   ```

   or

   ```
   docker-compose run web go build .
   docker-compose restart
   ```

   This should work because I'm using a volume to share code amongst the host and container. There shouldn't be a need to refetch all the dependencies. Shouldn't it use the freshly built executable? However, this does not reflect the built changes and port forwarding appears to break.

For reference, here is my *Dockerfile*:

```
FROM golang:1.8

COPY . /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1

RUN echo $PATH
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

RUN go build -o test1 .
CMD ["test1"]
EXPOSE 3470
```

And my *docker-compose.yml* file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/psql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./db/schema:/db/schema
  redis:
    image: redis
    volumes:
      - ./db/data/redis:/data
  server:
    build: .
    command: test1
    volumes:
      - .:/go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1
    ports:
      - "3470:3470"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Another thing you can try to speed up your builds is to copy over intermediary build artifacts from previous Docker builds, using `COPY --from`. You can have a look at my article about [Efficient Docker builds for large monorepos](https://medium.com/swlh/incremental-docker-builds-for-monolithic-codebases-2dae3ea950e), which also covers reducing image size using multi-stage builds, and making good use of the Docker build cache.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have asked a good question.

The command's order in the Dockerfile really matters. Put first the things that don't change frequently, and later those that are most likely to change in every build:

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

COPY . /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1

RUN echo $PATH

RUN go build -o test1 .
CMD ["test1"]
EXPOSE 3470
```

When a layer change regarding the previous build, docker discards the following cached layers and runs them again, sometimes wasting your time.

Pay attention to the "Using cache" sentence that docker outputs in each layer that is re-used from the previous build.

Another recommendation, for your dev work, use [fresh](https://github.com/pilu/fresh) to re-build your go app automatically every time you change the code. Just install it in the container and simply using `command: fresh` in your docker-compose.yml

Comment: I came across this comment about fresh. Can you elaborate on how you would setup fresh?

Answer (score 4):

And if you want to improve your Docker impl, you can make a smaller image. I suggest "multi-stage builds" to do that

> The image size for this build is like 600mb

```
FROM golang:1.8

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

COPY . /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1

RUN echo $PATH

RUN go build -o test1 .
CMD ["test1"]
EXPOSE 3470
```

> Using multi-stage builds, the image weight is the size of the binary and a scratch

```
FROM golang:1.8 as builder

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

COPY . /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1

RUN echo $PATH
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o test1 .


FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/

COPY --from=builder /go/src/github.com/codeblooded/test1 .

CMD ["test1"]

EXPOSE 3470
```

Using multi-stage builds you are using a heavy image for build the app and another really smaller for run your app.

Comment: Not sure multi-stage support rebuilding binary.